# why $post_id appears to have no value in functions.php but I can use it for get_the_title($post_id)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the function "a" I want to use in `add_action("the_content", "a")` in **functions.php**.

```
function a($content, $post_id){
   $x = get_the_title ($post_id);
   return $content.$x
}
```

When the post is loaded, I can see that the title appears after the content.

But actually what I want is to have the value of the post id, so I try

```
function a($content, $post_id){
   return $content.$post_id
}
```

And the post id is not showing at all.

Comment: opps forgot this is PHP...

Comment: So is it still not working with the . ?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($post_id)` and see what it actually contains?

Comment: @Stanyer the `.` was a typo I made unconsciously because I forgot the PHP syntax. I don't always code in PHP. The original problem is still there.

Comment: The WP Codex tells us that post ID for `get_the_title` is "(optional) The ID of the post or an object that specifies the post from which to get the title. __By default the current post is fetched.__" note the bold.. that's why it works.

Comment: @FDL oh no wonder I got NULL when dumping it. Got it! Thanks. So to get the ID I should use $wp_query->post->ID ?

Comment: You _might_ be able to get it using `get_the_ID();` - the function exists, its just whether it works in the loop (I assume it will) [post-template.php @ wpcodex](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)

Comment: @FDL Thanks! And great link! Will try that later.

Comment: I've added it as an answer - hope you get it sorted, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) if you pass a null value as the `$id` then WP will get the current post by default.

> The ID of the post or an object that specifies the post from which to get the title. **By default the current post is fetched.**

You could try using `get_the_ID();` instead to try and get the ID of the post if that's what you're after.